# Incorrect JSON Date

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am having trouble with the representation of a date in JSON.  I am using Service Stack as a web service to get the data from.  My code on the server side is as follows:

```
    public object Execute(GetNoPatientList request)
    {
        NoPatientList _noPatientList = new NoPatientList();

        List<string> _noMatchPatientList = new List<string>();
        List<NoPatientList> _newList = new List<NoPatientList>();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Database.WaldenWebConnection))
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cm.CommandText = "select [DateTimeStamp] as DateCreated,[ID],[PatientMRN],[FirstName],[MiddleName]"
                        + " ,[LastName],convert(varchar,[DOB],101) as DOB,[Sex],[Note],[Source] as Interface"
                        + " from PatientNoMatch"
                        + " where FoundMatch = 'F'"
                        + " and Show = 'T'"
                        + " order by DateTimeStamp desc";

                    SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        NoPatientList _noPatientList1 = new NoPatientList();

                        _noPatientList1.PatientMRN = dr["PatientMRN"].ToString();
                        _noPatientList1.FirstName = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                        _noPatientList1.MiddleName = dr["MiddleName"].ToString();
                        _noPatientList1.LastName = dr["LastName"].ToString();
                        _noPatientList1.DOB = dr["DOB"].ToString();
                        _noPatientList1.Sex = dr["Sex"].ToString();
                        _noPatientList1.Note = dr["Note"].ToString();
                        _noPatientList1.DateCreated = dr.GetDateTime(0);
                        _noPatientList1.Interface = dr["Interface"].ToString();

                        _newList.Add(_noPatientList1); 
                    }
                    return _newList;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return _newList;
        }
    }
```

The type is represented as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class NoPatientList
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PatientMRN { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Sex { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string DOB { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Note { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Interface { get; set; }

}
```

The web service is being consumed by a Silverlight application from the following call:

/InterfaceUtility/servicestack/json/syncreply/

The Silverlight application is processing the code into a grid using the following code

```
    private void GetNoPatientMatchData()
    {
        try
        {
            gridViewNoMatch.ItemsSource = null; 
        }
        catch { }
        _client = new WebClient();
        _client.OpenReadCompleted += (a, f) =>
        {
            if (!f.Cancelled && f.Error == null)
            {
                _listOfNoPatientsMatches = new List<NoPatientList>();                    
                MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                f.Result.CopyTo(_memoryStream);
                _memoryStream.Position = 0;

                StreamReader _streamReader = new StreamReader(_memoryStream);

                string _memoryStreamToText = _streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                List<NoPatientList> _deserializedNoPatientList = (List<NoPatientList>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_memoryStreamToText, typeof(List<NoPatientList>));                   
                gridViewNoMatch.ItemsSource = _deserializedNoPatientList;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(f.Error.Message,
                    "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        };

        _client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(_serviceUri + "getnopatientlist"));
```

The issue is that the times on DateTime field appear to always 6 hours off.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: if it's an exact hour (or rarely half-hour) multiple, then it's probably a time zone issue.

Comment: Would this be a time zone issue if both server getting and the computer where the Silverlight application is are in the same time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a time zone issue. Check that:

- Your webservice is returning you dates/times in UTC format.
- Your code is parsing these dates/times as UTC dates and times.

Comment: Would this be a time zone issue if both server getting and the computer where the Silverlight application is are in the same time zone?

Comment: It could very well be, because web services are usually by default set to return dates and times in UTC format. This is very simply because you don't know where your service consumers are going to be.